# SQL: My very short code times out; REGR_SLOPE is being super slow

Tags: sql, database, oracle, regression, timing

I'm pulling (read-only) information from a database that has a couple thousand rows in two different tables, one with 5 columns and one with 3 columns. Here's my code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT q1.MACHINE_ID, q1.SIGNAL_ID, ROUND(86400000*(REGR_SLOPE(ts.VALUE, ts.EPOCH) OVER (PARTITION BY ts.MACHINE_SIGNAL_ID))) AS RATE, q1.LAST_VALUE

FROM TSD_SUB ts,

( SELECT ms.MACHINE_SIGNAL_ID, ms.LAST_TIMESTAMP FROM MACHINE_SIGNAL ms
  WHERE (ms.MACHINE_ID LIKE 'CV%' OR ms.MACHINE_ID LIKE 'MT%')
  AND (ms.SIGNAL_ID = ANY('WFRCOUNT','WFRCNTR') OR ms.SIGNAL_ID LIKE '%WAFERCT%')) q1

WHERE ts.MACHINE_SIGNAL_ID = q1.MACHINE_SIGNAL_ID
  AND ts.EPOCH > (q1.LAST_TIMESTAMP - 604800000)
```

Now I'm not sure why it should take so long, but my code runs for over fifteen minutes until it times out. The inner bit,

```
SELECT * FROM MACHINE_SIGNAL
      WHERE (MACHINE_ID LIKE 'CV%' OR MACHINE_ID LIKE 'MT%')
      AND (SIGNAL_ID = ANY('WFRCOUNT','WFRCNTR') OR SIGNAL_ID LIKE '%WAFERCT%')
```

runs really quickly, pulling five columns and about three hundred rows. So the full code is using this (relatively small) table along with the larger table with two columns and a few thousand rows.

This database is an Oracle database, and so running the REGR_SLOPE works fine. Additionally, if I just try to run the outer code a little at a time, it works fine:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ROUND(86400000*(REGR_SLOPE(ts.VALUE, ts.EPOCH) OVER (PARTITION BY ts.MACHINE_SIGNAL_ID))) AS RATE

FROM tsd_sub ts

WHERE ts.machine_signal_id = '366625' -- taken from MACHINE_SIGNAL_ID of the first row of the previous code
  AND ts.epoch > (1436855226000 - 604800000) -- from LAST_TIMESTAMP of the first row from the previous code
```

runs in less than two seconds and gives me a one-cell result. But I want it for every entry in my inner table, not just one entry at a time. And that's not running at all.

I know it's possibly taking so long because I'm pulling so many entries, but I'm only asking it to do two things so I don't understand why it's not running at all. It's almost like it's going into infinite loop, except that I don't see why it would do that.

Thank you for your time and help!

---

EDIT:

The table MACHINE_SIGNAL has a variable MACHINE_SIGNAL_ID which only appears once in MACHINE_SIGNAL, but appears many times in TSD_SUB. So I'm just trying to calculate the REGR_SLOPE of the multiple rows in TSD_SUB to correspond to the one row in MACHINE_SIGNAL. But yeah, I can't just join the tables, because TSD_SUB has too many rows for each value of MACHINE_SIGNAL_ID in MACHINE_SIGNAL.

---

The following also takes far too long to run:

```
SELECT MACHINE_SIGNAL_ID, 
       ROUND(86400000*(REGR_SLOPE(ts.VALUE, ts.EPOCH))) AS RATE

FROM TSD_SUB ts, 

    (SELECT DISTINCT (Max(ts0.EPOCH) - 604800000) AS YESTERDAY 
     FROM TSD_SUB ts0 
     WHERE ROWNUM < 100) ts1

WHERE ts.EPOCH > ts1.YESTERDAY

GROUP BY MACHINE_SIGNAL_ID
```

This means that joining it with MACHINE_SIGNAL won't work at all, unless I can also restrict by the MACHINE_SIGNAL_ID values that I look for in MACHINE_SIGNAL, but I can't look for those values without looking at MACHINE_SIGNAL first. It feels like a catch-22 problem.

---

The following code does work, so HURRAY thank you all for your help.

```
SELECT ms.MACHINE_ID, ms.SIGNAL_ID, ms.MACHINE_SIGNAL_ID, ms.Last_Value, ts.EPOCH, ts.VALUE

FROM MACHINE_SIGNAL ms JOIN
     (SELECT ts.MACHINE_SIGNAL_ID, ts.EPOCH, ts.VALUE FROM TSD_SUB ts, 
                    (SELECT (Max(ts0.EPOCH) - 604800000) AS YESTERDAY 
                     FROM TSD_SUB ts0 
                     WHERE ROWNUM < 1000) ts1
               WHERE ts.EPOCH > ts1.YESTERDAY) ts
     on ts.machine_signal_id = ms.machine_signal_id

WHERE (ms.MACHINE_ID LIKE 'CV%' OR ms.MACHINE_ID LIKE 'MT%') AND
      (ms.SIGNAL_ID IN ('WFRCOUNT', 'WFRCNTR') OR SIGNAL_ID LIKE '%WAFERCT%')
```

Now my problem is figuring out how to get the REGR_SLOPE from this new table per each MACHINE_SIGNAL_ID rather than getting it from the entire table. This is possibly a new problem, so I will get back to you on that.

---

Yeah for some reason even though the code above joining the tables works, the surrounding bit calculating the REGR_SLOPE is still timing out. Below is the full code, with the parts that do work marked with comments.

```
SELECT myTable.MACHINE_ID, 
       myTable.SIGNAL_ID, 
       ROUND(86400000*REGR_SLOPE(myTable.VALUE, myTable.EPOCH)) AS RATE, 
       myTable.Last_Value

FROM
-- THIS PART WORKS PERFECTLY WELL --
(SELECT ms.MACHINE_ID, ms.SIGNAL_ID, ms.MACHINE_SIGNAL_ID, ms.Last_Value, ts.EPOCH, ts.VALUE

FROM MACHINE_SIGNAL ms JOIN
     (SELECT ts.MACHINE_SIGNAL_ID, ts.EPOCH, ts.VALUE FROM TSD_SUB ts, 
                    (SELECT (Max(ts0.EPOCH) - 604800000) AS YESTERDAY 
                     FROM TSD_SUB ts0 
                     WHERE ROWNUM < 1000) ts1
               WHERE ts.EPOCH > ts1.YESTERDAY) ts
     on ts.machine_signal_id = ms.machine_signal_id

WHERE (ms.MACHINE_ID LIKE 'CV%' OR ms.MACHINE_ID LIKE 'MT%') AND
      (ms.SIGNAL_ID IN ('WFRCOUNT', 'WFRCNTR') OR SIGNAL_ID LIKE '%WAFERCT%')) myTable
-- UP TO HERE IS A VALID TABLE WHICH RUNS IN LESS THAN A SECOND --

Group BY myTable.MACHINE_SIGNAL_ID, myTable.MACHINE_ID, myTable.SIGNAL_ID, myTable.Last_Value
```

The only things of substance here that are added are the REGR_SLOPE and the GROUP BY but even when REGR_SLOPE has a PARTITION inside of it (as I had in the beginning) it still times out. This implies that the REGR_SLOPE function is just doing something I'm not expecting that's making it be terribly slow. If it's going through every row, how do I make it stop, and if it's not, why is it being so slow?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it would help, but perhaps writing your query more sensibly would help the optimizer.  I am guessing that this is the equivalent query:

```
SELECT ms.MACHINE_ID, ms.SIGNAL_ID,
       ROUND(86400000*(REGR_SLOPE(ts.VALUE, ts.EPOCH))) AS RATE,
       ms.LAST_VALUE
FROM MACHINE_SIGNAL JOIN
     tsd_sub ts
     on ts.machine_signal_id = ms.machine_signal_id
WHERE (ms.MACHINE_ID LIKE 'CV%' OR ms.MACHINE_ID LIKE 'MT%') AND
      (ms.SIGNAL_ID IN ('WFRCOUNT', 'WFRCNTR') OR SIGNAL_ID LIKE '%WAFERCT%') AND
      ts.epoch > (q1.LAST_TIMESTAMP - 604800000)
GROUP BY ms.MACHINE_ID, ms.SIGNAL_ID, ms.LAST_VALUE;
```

This assumes that `signal_id` is identifying the `machine_id` and `last_value`.  It is replacing the analytic function with an aggregation function.

Your version of the query runs the regression for every row produced by the join *and then* does a distinct.  Just use a `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

Shortness of code has nothing to do with performance. In fact longer code in SQl is often the better choice.

I am sure Oracle has some equivalent of a SQL Server execution plan or mysql explainplan. You need to find what that is and run it to see what is causing the slowdown.

I don't know anything about Oracle performance as it is very differnt than the things that make queries slow in SQl Server but you will want to look to see if you are doing table scans or using indexxes. You will want to see how many reads on the table.

I do know you are doing some things that are performance issues in most databases. First you are only using one column in the derived table, so don't use select *.  That is a SQL antipattern in pretty much all databases.  Distinct of course makes things slower but is not alwys reasy to avoid.

Functions often make it harder to use indexes and starting a like condition with a wildcard is usually a bad idea.

One thing I might consider trying is replacing this code:

```
DISTINCT q1.MACHINE_ID, q1.SIGNAL_ID, ROUND(86400000*(REGR_SLOPE(ts.VALUE, ts.EPOCH)
```

Instead write a derived table that gets the DISTINCT q1.MACHINE_ID, q1.SIGNAL_ID, ts.VALUE, ts.EPOCH and then do the calculation only agaist your distinct rows.  Right now it is running the function against all rows before being able to do the distinct part.

Answer (score 0):

First think about for which data you need to calculate the regression slope. Based on your PARTITION BY clause it is MACHINE_SIGNAL_ID.

Put this column(s) in GROUP BY
Don't use analytic function (PARTITION BY) and
DISTINCT

Start with a query like this

```
SELECT MACHINE_SIGNAL_ID, 
    ROUND(86400000*(REGR_SLOPE(ts.VALUE, ts.EPOCH))) AS RATE
FROM TSD_SUB ts
WHERE .. add filter predicated to limit records
GROUP BY MACHINE_SIGNAL_ID
```

Join the result with other tables if you need additional info.